# I need the Y axis values in integer instead of decimal values in Dynamic Chart

Tags: highcharts

I am using Dynamic chart in [Hightcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update).

I want integer values in Y Axis instead of decimal values.

Can any one guide me where I can made changes to make this values integer.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: ... just have integer values in your data? The labels won't show decimals if there isn't a reason to.

Comment: Set `yAxis.allowDecimals` to false. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1ym68nd0/

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) just removed decimal point!